# Is it correct to say "to make her acknowledge"?

Tags: grammaticality

I came across a sentence in a blog post that says

> ...to make her acknowledge the fact that I loved her.

Is it correct to write *make a person acknowledge a fact* or is there a better way this could be put up?

Comment: it's correct, but not very romantic at least :D it sounds like from a British porn, haha. "We could have sex, Mary." - "We very well could, but let's not. Let's acknowledge the fact that we love each other." - "Very well indeed."

Comment: Is this about English usage? Seems more appropriate for writers.SE, Philosophy.SE, or self-actualization.SE.

Comment: @Jasper: OK. But then VeeKay should clarify in the question: is it about the grammaticality? is it about 'to make her', is it appropriate to apply it to something so tame as acknowledgement? If the former, that's very ELU; if the latter, not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything particularly "impolite" in the phrasing. [Here's](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=acknowledge%20her%20love,acknowledge%20his%20love&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) an NGram showing hundreds of written instances of *acknowledge his/her love*, which suggests such usage may have been more common in the past (i.e. - in an age when impolite phrasing would have been less likely to make it into print).

As implied by my search terms above, the only thing I might suggest by way of an improvement is replacing *the fact that I loved her* with *my love*. Besides being shorter (often a good thing in itself), I feel it has more a sense of romantic chivalry.

Grammatically it's impossible to criticise use of the past tense *loved* without knowing the preceding context. If preceded by *I'm trying*, for example, the writer would use *love* or *loved* depending purely on whether he still does love her at time of writing.

If preceded by *I was trying*, we enter the murky world of common usage, precise grammar, and semantics. Some people might say that using *loved* still implies, as above, that the speaker *no longer loves her*. I personally think there is no such implication, no do I see it as ungrammatical. Take, for example...

**I said that I was a native English speaker.**

...which seems perfectly valid to me, even though obviously I must *still* be a native speaker. Choice of *I was* or *I am* is just a matter of style and emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very polite way of putting it.  "Make" can have forceful, negative connotations.

Consider:

```
"...to help her understand that I loved her..."
```

or

```
"...to show that I loved her..."
```